# I have got error " java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present " when coding with Spring boot API. Please help check and resolve issue.Thanks

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have got error " java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present ".Please help me to check and resolve.

[image]

Comment: don't post images of code. don't post links to images of code. Post your actual code, formatted as code (and stick to the relevant part). Post a(ny) error message you get. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your `Optional<Employee>` is empty.

You forgot to `return`  inside your `if` statement.

```
if(!result.isPresent() {
    System.out.println("Id: " + id + " don't exist");

    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
}
```